# ipython from windows command line

Tags: ipython

I changed the environment variable PATH, to a new value and then back to what I believe was the original one. But now I can't open a .ipynb file through the Windows command line the was I was used to.

After changing the directory in command line and running

`ipython notebook notebook_name.ipynb`

I get the following message:

> 'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

My environment variable is set to a folder with python.exe, and this folder includes a subfolder with ipython.exe and jupyter-notebook.exe. When I open iPython command line and type %env, I can see the full path to the correct subfolder under PATH.

Can someone point to a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you figured out that you have to set the extension association in System Settings.

I've found that I'm using Notebooks often enough that it was well worth using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) with the following script to open the Jupyter Notebook server in my default directory (or the currently highlighted directory in Explorer)

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoTrayIcon

SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

; Press CTRL+ALT+I in a Windows Explorer window to launch a IPython notebook server in the current folder.
^+!i::
; Get the current path.
Send ^l
; Backup the current clipboard.
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
; Copy and save the current path.
Send ^c
ClipWait
x = %Clipboard%
; Restore the clipboard.
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved = ; Free the memory in case the clipboard was very large.
; Now, run the IPython notebook server.
RunWait, ipython notebook --notebook-dir "%x%", , min
return

^i::
; Now, run the IPython notebook server.
RunWait, jupyter notebook --notebook-dir "C:\Path\To\WorkSpace", , min
return

; Press CTRL+ALT+P to kill all Python processes.
^!p::
Run, taskkill /f /im python.exe, , min
return
```

Answer (score 3):

So I figured out a solution - I changed the environment variable PATH to the subfolder with the .exe files. Although the path including this subfolder was listed under %env, it did not work without being referred directly in the System setting.